# Uniqueness of transactionIdentifier in canceled SKPaymentTransaction

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm in the midst of tying my current app's IAP code with our backend server. One thing I was thinking of doing was to also use it to record canceled and/or failed transactions.

This brought up the question as to whether or not the transactionIdentifier for these types of transactions are considered unique? More specifically in the cancel case, I'm not quite sure if it is generating a temp identifier and then replacing it with one given by the App Store. And if so, is the temp one still unique?

I do happen to notice in Xcode a data member in SKPaymentTransaction called `_temporaryIdentifier`, which got me thinking about this possible scenario.

Note that I don't have to surface cancelled transactions to our server. I Just thought it would be helpful to have. It seems that I probably do need to send failure since I believe a deferred transaction that is not allowed will result in a failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't count on them being unique, they are considered *undefined* for any state other than `purchased` or `restored`.

It is explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction/1411288-transactionidentifier) for `transactionIdentifier`:

> A string that uniquely identifies a **successful** payment transaction
>   [...]
>   The contents of this property are undefined except when 
>   transactionState is set to purchased or restored.

Comment: Many thanks. Apparently I've lost the ability to read. I would have sworn I read that page ... but clearly not!! :D

Comment: Well, regardless... you asked an interesting question. I have read that page before as well, but I never really *consciously* registered that the ID is only 'set in stone' after a *successful* purchase. Learned something new as well, that's why I love StackOverflow haha :D